# Why does not data change after clicking submit button in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I click Edit button to submit the data it just refreshes the page. I have spent hours to solve the problem. Though it does not show any error and it does not change the database. I can not fix the problem why it is happening.
Model class for Student

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Student Name")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please enter Email")]
    [Remote("IsEmailUnique","Student",ErrorMessage = "This Email is 
                  already Exists")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "please fill up Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    [Required]
    [DataType(dataType:DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", 
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public  DateTime DoB { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("IsPhoneUnique", "Student", ErrorMessage = "This Phone is 
             already Exists")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Reg NO")]
    [Remote("IsRegNoUnique", "Student", ErrorMessage = "This RegNo is 
     already Exists")]
    public string RegNo { get; set; }  
}
```

*Controller for edit*

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var student = db.Students.Find(id);

    ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", " 
              "DepartmentName");

    return View(student);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(student).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.id = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName", student.DepartmentId);
    return View(student);
}
```

*View for Edit*

```
@model CampusManagementApp.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Make A Booking";
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Student"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "DepartmentId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId",
                (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.id,
                "Select department")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoB, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoB)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DoB)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <b>Male</b>@Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male")
                <b>Female</b>
                @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

What can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: My guess is `ModelState.IsValid` is returning `false`. Put a breakpoint in your HttpPost action method and verify that.

Comment: No mater how much they may look like Desktop GUI, ASP.Net Application are still 1980 HTML WebFormulars. All those poor decision the designers made 4 decades ago are still in full effect. If you have any issue, usually a good place to start is to learn the HTML limitations. And how you have been working around them.

Comment: We need to see more code. Specifically, what the HTML form looks like and what the Student model class looks like. Otherwise, it's hard to say what the issue could be. But it's likely that ModelState.IsValid is returning false like Shyju said.

Comment: Please show the Student model that you are posting to server, and your view, as shown above, does not contain Student Model. You view also does not show the presence of anti forgery token.

Comment: model Class for student has been added

Comment: View for Edit student hal aslo be included.@Hooman

Answer (score 2):

You have at least one validation error, because `RegNo` is required and is not even part of your view.

As suggested in the comments, best is to put a breakpoint on this line of your controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

And check if there are any other validation errors...

Comment: yes it works after adding regNo in Edit view,thanks